# apache cxf ContainerRequestContext is returning always null

Tags: java, json, web-services, jax-rs, cxf

I have a class AuthorizationFilter which implements ContainerRequestFilter.

```
@Provider
@Authorization
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws 
IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InputStream entityIn = requestContext.getEntityStream();

  }

}
```

This filter should be called before this method:

```
@Path("/delete/volume")
@Authorization
public Response deleteVolumeForTechAccount(VolumeRequestJSON volumeForDeletion) {
    log.debug("Delete volume was called ");

    VolumeOperation operator = getVolumeOperator();

    try {
        log.debug("Deleting volume with id: " + volumeForDeletion.getVolumeId());

        operator.deleteVolume(volumeForDeletion.getVolumeId());

        log.debug("Volume with id: " + volumeForDeletion.getVolumeId() + "was deleted");

        return Response.ok().build();
    } catch (OperationException ex) {
        log.error("OperationException occured durring deletion of volume: " + volumeForDeletion.getVolumeId(), ex);

        return buildResponseWithHeader(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR, ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I am calling the rest with the following JSON data :

{"volumeId":"test"}

The method is executed successfully but when I call:

requestContext.getEntityStream() in the filter it returns always null.

I would like to read the json data in the filter.

Please explain if I am doing something wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because I was using an old version of apache cxf bundle.
When I changed the version to:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
<version>2.7.18</version>
</dependency>
```

the issue was fixed.

Also the issue was officially submitted to apache cxf.
Here is the link: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5243